# Per-mode value for `fill-column'

Tags: fill-column

Emacs and I agree on many things.  That's good.  However, there is one thing we disagree on – the default value for `fill-column` for different major modes.  In order to alleviate this, I added the following to my init file:

```
(let ((fill-column-mode-alist '((org-mode . 80)
                                (markdown-mode . 80)
                                (tex-mode . 80)
                                (python-mode . 79))))
  (defun modify-fill-column-maybe ()
    "Call `set-fill-column' with a value according to the major mode."
    (let ((value (assoc major-mode
                        fill-column-mode-alist
                        #'provided-mode-derived-p)))
      (when value
        (set-fill-column (cdr value))))))

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook #'modify-fill-column-maybe)
```

My question is whether there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach.  Any pitfalls that I am overlooking?  Is there maybe a built-in functionality for this that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's anything *wrong* with what you're doing. If it works I don't see any obvious pitfalls.

That said, it's not the usual way to apply mode-specific settings. This is usually done with a mode-hook. For example, I have the following in my init:

```
(defun my-org-src-mode-hook ()
  (setq fill-column 65)
  (auto-fill-mode t))

(add-hook 'org-src-mode-hook #'my-org-src-mode-hook)
```

If the only thing you're tweaking for each mode is the fill-column value, your way is probably more convenient. But if you've got other mode-specific config, it may be more convenient to organize it by mode (i.e., with mode hooks), rather than by feature.

Comment: Thank you.  For some reason I have opted to organize things, as you say, by feature.  For example, In my `use-package` declaration for `flyspell`, I have `:hook ((org-mode markdown-mode TeX-mode) . flyspell-mode)`.  Maybe I should consider doing things the other way around!

Comment: Ha! I didn't know use-package had a :hook argument, that's handy.

Comment: @Tyler: please add a `#` before `'my-org-src-mode-hook` so the compiler knows it is a function.

Comment: @DamienCassou ok. I understand why, but the official docs don't cover this, and the `#'` syntax differs from the examples of add-hook in the manuals. It would be helpful if the official Emacs manual explicitly covered this. The only mention of `#'` is in relation to anonymous functions.

Comment: I have tried for `(defun LaTeX-mode-hook ()
  (setq fill-column 120)
  (auto-fill-mode t))` but seems like column size still remains at 80, should I make additional change for it?

Comment: @alper you should be defining `my-latex-mode-hook`, and then adding it to `LaTeX-mode-hook` via `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my-latex-mode-hook)`